# Global mouse hook в консоли

Tags: c#, winapi, hook, pinvoke

Пытаюсь познакомиться с работой WinAPI в C#. Нужно сделать mouse hook, который будет следить за движением мыши по всему экрану и получать координаты курсора при движении. У меня это консольное приложение и поэтому Windows.Form я не использую.

Я нашел пример кода, который привожу ниже, который реализует нужную мне задачу с использованием Windows.Form и обменом сообщений через Application.Run().

Мне на данный момент нужно сделать то же самое, но сообщениями нужно обмениваться с консолью и координаты, соответственно, выводить в консоль. При этом слежение за мышью должно происходить не только в окне консоли, но и по всему экрану.

Как это можно реализовать?

```
class InterceptMouse
{
    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;

    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

        Application.Run();

        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)

        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,

                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            Console.WriteLine(hookStruct.pt.x + ", " + hookStruct.pt.y);
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

    private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);


    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Comment: Можно к консольному приложению подключить сборку `System.Windows.Forms.dll` и использовать свойство [Cursor.Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position(v=vs.110).aspx). Сейчас проверил - вроде работает.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался в вопросе, посмотрев примеры кода на с++.
То, что мне было нужно - перехват сообщений от windowsAPI в консоль, возможно с помощью функций windowsAPI GetMessage, TranslateMessage, DispatchMessage.
Приведу пример кода: 
Переопределяем указанные функции + структуру MSG:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr DispatchMessage([In] ref MSG lpmsg);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool TranslateMessage([In] ref MSG lpMsg);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern sbyte GetMessage(out MSG lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin,
       uint wMsgFilterMax);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
    public struct MSG
    {
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public UInt32 message;
        public UIntPtr wParam;
        public UIntPtr lParam;
        public UInt32 time;
        public POINT pt;
    }
```

Используем так:

```
static bool Main2(IntPtr hinstance, IntPtr hPrevInstance, string lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER for set mouse hook...");
        _hookKeyboardID = SetHook(_procKeyboard);

        MSG msg;

        sbyte hasMessage;

        while ((hasMessage = WinAPI.GetMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0)) != 0 && hasMessage != -1)
        {
            WinAPI.TranslateMessage(ref msg);
            WinAPI.DispatchMessage(ref msg);
        }

        return msg.wParam == UIntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

А этот main2 уже оборачиваем в другой, который передает аргументы от конкретного процесса:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Main2(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, IntPtr.Zero, string.Empty, (int)ShowWindowCommands.Normal);
    }
```

Надеюсь, кому-то в будущем это сэкономит значительное время.